# Azure DevOps (az apim nv create) cant able to create variable dynamically

Tags: azure, azure-devops, apim

I'm trying to create multiple values using "az apim nv create" command using loop, but its not working.

with the single command (without using variable in --value) we can able to create, but the same is not working when we use variable in --value.

```
demo="fromkey fromkey1"
for list in $demo
do
az apim nv create --service-name ABC -g XYZ --secret true --named-value-id $list --display-name $list --value $list
done
```

Can someone please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure DevOps (az apim nv create) cant able to create variable dynamically

You could try below scripts in the bash task:

```
- bash: |
    demo=( "fromkey" "fromkey1" )
    for list in ${demo[@]}; do
      az apim nv create --service-name ABC -g XYZ --secret true --named-value-id $list --display-name $list --value $list
    done
  displayName: 'az apim nv create'
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
```

**Update:**

> I this can be possible with Shell script ? if Yes then can you please
> share shell script commands

```
declare -a demo=("fromkey1" "fromkey2" "fromkey3")

for list in "${demo[@]}"
do
   az apim nv create --service-name ABC -g XYZ --secret true --named-value-id $list --display-name $list --value $list
done
```

Comment: Hi Leo Liu, thanks a lot for sharing the commands, 
I this can be possible with Shell script ? if Yes then can you please share shell script commands

Comment: @karthikN, It's time for me to get off work, I'll find time tomorrow to try it

Comment: sure Leo, thanks for the update.

Comment: Hi Leo Liu, in your feasible time can you please share the shell script plz. 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: @karthikN, Sorry for the late reply, I've been stuck on other threads lately until today. Please check the update answer in the above answer.

Comment: NP Leo, thanks a lot for helping me. I've tried but its not working as expected  <br/>`az apim nv create --service-name ABC -g XYZ --secret true --named-value-id $list --display-name $list --value $(newkey-1-4-22)`  <br/>  
The above command is updating correctly with Key name and Key Value,
   `az apim nv create --service-name ABC -g XYZ --secret true --named-value-id $list --display-name $list --value $list`
but the above command is storing Key name with "Key Name" and also Key value is with "Key Name" only. $list is not taking the value also tried with `$(list)` but no luck